# Where am I going wrong in getting this function to do what I would like?

Tags: c

I have written the following function in my C program. The program loads a text file (Les Miserables Vol. I) as well as another text file of 20 of the characters names. The purpose of this function is to scan the entire file, line by line, and count the number of times any of the 20 names appear.

`NumOfNames` = 20.

`Names` is an array of the 20 names stored from `Names[1]` - `Names[20]`.

`MaxName` is a global integer variable which I would like to store the total number of name appearances throughout the file (It should be in the hundreds or even thousands).

**EDIT:** After the function is executed, the value of MaxName is 4. I am completely lost as to where I have made a mistake, but it appears that I have made several mistakes throughout the function. One seems to be that it only executed the first iteration of the for loop i.e. it only searches for `Name[1]`, however the first name appears 196 times in the file, so it still isnt even working correctly for just the first name.

```
void MaxNameAppearances()
{
    char LineOfText[85];
    char *TempName;
    FILE *fpn = fopen(LesMisFilePath, "r+");

    for(i = 1; i<=NumOfNames; i++)
    {
        while(fgets(LineOfText, sizeof(LineOfText), fpn))
        {
            TempName = strstr(LineOfText, Names[i]);

            if(TempName != NULL)
            {
                MaxName++;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fpn);
}
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are having with your code?

Comment: You should note that arrays start with index 0 in C, so `Names` is not `Names[1] - Names[20]` but `Names[0] - Names[19]`.

Comment: I know that but I have created the array so that the first element is blank and then the following elements hold names 1-20. My program needs the names to be stored in the array in the correct position (1st name in `Names[1]` etc.

Comment: @KOB Don't do that. It's an awful habit to start. Indices start at 0, because that's how computers work.

Comment: For performance it would be better to swap iterations: read line from file and iterate then over names

Comment: Ok thanks, I can change that easily. Now back to the main problem that's driving me crazy!!

Comment: @j.holetzeck I have tried both ways but cannot get either working correctly, Any sample codes for a way to accomplish what I am trying to do would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If a name appears SPLIT at a border of your buffer size - then you will not get a strstr() hit on it: e.g. the first character of  a name is at position 85 in the file...

Comment: You cannot read 85 bytes into a 85-byte buffer.

Comment: @Hannu Each line in the file is less than 85 characters long

Comment: The code assumes the text to be ASCII/ECMA-Latin-1 or similar.

Comment: You said it only searches for `Name[1]`. That is because your repeatedly calling `fgets` in the first loop finishes reading the entire file. Then when you loop for `Name[2]`, there is nothing left to read.

Comment: @ArjunShankar So I need to add an `fseek` function to the beginning of the file at the end of eachiteration of the for loop?

Comment: No. Switch the loops like in @ThorstenDittmar's answer.  You want to read it once. It is faster to access the hard drive once rather than reading it 20 times.

Comment: I'd recommend using all the suggestions pointed out here and then sharing new results/issues. But we cannot really help you debug your program like this. Use a debugger. I'd highly recommend it. If you're using gcc on a Linux, for example, then gdb would be one possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that one problem of the code is that it would have to read the file upon every iteration of `i`. Try to re-order the loops like this:

```
while(fgets(LineOfText, sizeof(LineOfText), fpn))
{
    for(i = 1; i<=NumOfNames; i++)
    {
        TempName = strstr(LineOfText, Names[i]);
        if(TempName != NULL)
        {
            MaxName++;
        }
    }
}
```

This reads a line, checks the occurrances of all names in that line and then goes on to the next line.

If you do it your way, you will be at the end of file for `i == 1` already.

Comment: This catches one of the problems. I think it would also make sense to recommend using the usual `for (i = 0; ...; ...)` style. The loop used by the OP is not a C idiom at all. I wouldn't be surprised if the array declaration uses a size of 20, and there's a subtle bug waiting to occur when they eventually start working with an illegal `Name[20]`.

Comment: With the code editted to your suggestion, `MaxName` now has a value of 14 at the end of the fucntion, whereas it should be in the hundreds or even thousands.

@ArjunShankar I have `char **Names` declared as a global variable and then in a previous function I have the line: 

`Names = malloc((NumOfNames+1)*sizeof(*Names));`

This should accomodate for `Name[20]`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @KOB It might be correct to have 1 extra element and start counting from 1 instead of 0. But it is not idiomatic C. i.e. people don't usually write like that. It is confusing. One day, you'll forget the 1 extra element; or somebody else will read your code and be confused. Best to count from 0. That being said, it's obviously not the problem here. Our problem is: We cannot debug your problem if we don't have a [complete example](http://sscce.org/) that we can compile and run to see ourselves. Plus, you're wasting your own time by not using a [debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger).

Comment: @ArjunShankar Thank you for your feedback. I am relatively new to programming and so please excuse my lack of details. I have never used a debugger either so I will swiftly look into this. I don't know the best way to share my code with you, so here is the code and the two neccessary file shared from Google Drive. The two files should be stored in the folder outlined in the first couple of lines of the code. 

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7qDUDai7Ylofnp4eHQteGZJMGhoZjRCS1NCbEJfMzc3STllR2lsVHNCYk5yT2Ffal9UeEk&usp=sharing